# Splits up two comma separated items, if they exist

Tags: c#, iterator

This method splits up two comma separated items, if they exist, and increments the amount if the are already in the list; otherwise add the item to the list

I want to know if this code can be optimized some more. Any suggestions?

The method below works 100% fine but I feel like it is not neatly done.

```
private void SeperateJoinedDisposables(IEnumerable<Models.Container> joinedDisposables)
{
    if (!joinedDisposables.Any())
        return;

    foreach (var item in joinedDisposables.ToList())
    {
        var amount = item.Amount;
        var container = item.Container;

        var disposable1 = container.Substring(0, container.IndexOf(","));
        var disposable2 = container.Substring(container.IndexOf(",") + 1);

        DisposablesModel.Containers.Remove(item);

        var disposableCointians1 = DisposablesModel.Containers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Container.ToUpper().Contains(disposable1.ToUpper()));
        var disposableCointians2 = DisposablesModel.Containers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Container.ToUpper().Contains(disposable2.ToUpper()));

        if (disposableCointians1 != null)
            disposableCointians1.Amount = (int.Parse(disposableCointians1.Amount) + int.Parse(amount)).ToString();
        else
            DisposablesModel.Containers.Add(new Models.Container { Amount = amount, Container = disposable1 });

        if (disposableCointians2 != null)
            disposableCointians2.Amount = (int.Parse(disposableCointians2.Amount) + int.Parse(amount)).ToString();
        else
            DisposablesModel.Containers.Add(new Models.Container { Amount = amount, Container = disposable2 });
    }
}
```

Here is my model class

```
    public class DisposablesModel
    {
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string RushColor { get; set; }
        public string RushDescription { get; set; }
        public string Pollution { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfSamples { get; set; }
        public List<Container> Containers { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubcontracted { get; set; }
    }

    public class Container
    {
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        public string Container { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: is `items.Container` a typo?  `item` is of type `Models.Container`, therefore it can't have a member of the same name.

Comment: It would be great question if you just provided a sample input and include `Models.Container` class as well.

Comment: I've included the model class in the edited version. @iSR5

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

- The class "Container" has a property named "Container"? That is... confusing, to say the least. Hence you having to name it `item` when iterating through it, which is unclear (and thus bad).
- "Cointians" has two typos.
- If you need to have a case insensitive `Contains()`, there are better ways to do it than use `ToUpper()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54686459/648075
- Do not copy-paste logic when it is the same for two cases; instead move it to a method and call it.
- Why is the property Amount a `string` instead of an `int`? Your code constantly needs to converts `string`s to `int`s and vice versa; why not use the proper types instead and avoid all that?
- Is the Container of a Container always a comma-separated string of two items? Why then not make it a `List<string> Names`?

---

Most impotantly: due to the bad names, I have trouble figuring out what your code actually does.

That `joinedDisposables` is a list of `Container`s is unclear, and due to "Container" being both the name of a class as well as one of its properties the code becomes even more unclear.

I have the impression that once your `Container` class has a "proper" structure, much of this code can be replaced by simple LINQ queries; it's just that the bad names and the bad structures obfuscate so much it makes things hard to grasp.

To me it looks like `public List<Container> Containers { get; set; }` should be a `Dictionary<string, int>`, and that what you pass to `SeperateJoinedDisposables` should be a `List<string>` where each `string` is a comma separated list. And then your code would be something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> Containers = new Dictionary<string, int>();

private void Parse(List<string> commaSeparatedValues)
{
    foreach (var commaSeparatedValue in commaSeparatedValues)
    {
        foreach (var value in commaSeparatedValue.Split(','))
        {
            var normalisedValue = value.ToLower();

            if (!Containers.TryGetValue(normalisedValue, out int count))
            {
                count = 0;
            }

            count++;
            Containers[normalisedValue] = count;
        }
    }
}
```

To me this code expresses far more clearly the intent of what you're trying to do -- if I correctly understand the purpose of your code, of course.

But then I don't know where `IEnumerable<Models.Container> joinedDisposables` comes from and how it is constructed and why it is constructed that way, so I can only assume a "better" solution based on limited knowledge.

Comment: IEnumerable<Models.Container> joinedDisposables comes from an Api call and can sometimes contain elements that are comma separated and if so it would never be more than 2 elements that is split by a comma.